# swagger $ref, Could not resolve reference: Tried to resolve a relative URL, without having a basePath. path: 'user.yaml' basePath: 'undefined'

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I changed $ref value several times,
but all of them reveal same error... help me plz
what's wrong?

[swagger-ui error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VjXF.png)
[my directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t7za.png)

swagger.js

```
import swaggereJsdoc from 'swagger-jsdoc';

const options = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      title: 'User API',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'User API with express',
    },
    host: 'localhost:8000',
    // basePath: '/api',
  },
  apis: ['./routers/*.js', './swagger/*'],
};

export const specs = swaggereJsdoc(options);
```

user-router.js

```
/**
 * @swagger
 *  /api/users:
 *    get:
 *      tags:
 *      - user
 *      description: users (array)
 *      produces:
 *      - application/json
 *      responses:
 *       '200':
 *          description: success getUsers
 *
 *          schema:
 *            $ref: './swagger/user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
 */
```

user.yaml

```
# /swagger/user.yml

components:
  schemas:
    User:
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          description: primary key
```

testing code before this question:

```
$ref: './swagger/user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
$ref: '/swagger/user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
$ref: 'swagger/user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
$ref: './user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
$ref: '/user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
$ref: 'user.yaml#/components/schemas/User'
```

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Facing this exact problem :(